# How to disable button and change button name when data is processed

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I have a delete button which I use to delete table rows:

```
//Dialog
function deletedialog(a){              
    $("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $("#form\\:deleterow").click();
              //  $('input[id$="deleterow"]').click();               
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
            } 
        }
    });

}

<h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- the delete button -->
<h:commandButton value="Delete">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="deletedialog('Do you want to delete the selected rows?')"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

I want when I press the delete button during the execution time of the Java delete method to disable it. I also want to change the visual name if the button from "Delete" to "Processing" like the buttons in Glassfish. This case is little more complicated because I use hidden button. How I can do this?

**Post Update**

```
<!-- the delete button -->
<h:button value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog('Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />
```

**Post Update 2**

I edited the code this way:

```
//Dialog
function deletedialog(button, a){
    button.value = "Processing...";
    button.disabled = true;    
    $("<div />", {
        text: a
    }).dialog({        
        width: 600,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() { 
                $("#form\\:deleterow").click();
              //  $('input[id$="deleterow"]').click();               
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                button.value = "Delete";
                button.disabled = false;

            }, 
            "Cancel": function(event) { 
                $(this).dialog("close");
                event.preventDefault();
                button.value = "Delete";
                button.disabled = false;
            } 
        }
    });

}

<!-- hidden button -->
<h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{SessionsController.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
    <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

<!-- the delete button -->
<h:button value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog(this, 'Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />
```

Well the button works. The problem is that when I click delete button the button is disabled only for the time when the dialog is opened. I need to keep the button disabled when I perform the background database operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the proper usage of the `onevent` attribute. The `onevent` attribute should point to a special function which is invoked on *every* ajax event (begin, complete and success) in which JSF will supply the data argument itself. E.g.

```html
<f:ajax ... onevent="functionname" />
```

with

```js
function functionname(data) {
    var ajaxStatus = data.status; // Can be 'begin', 'complete' and 'success'.

    switch (ajaxStatus) {
        case 'begin': // This is called right before ajax request is been sent.
            // ...
            break;

        case 'complete': // This is called right after ajax response is received.
            // ...
            break;

        case 'success': // This is called when ajax response is successfully processed.
            // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

This is useful to for example show an ajax progress/status image, or to disable/enable the submit button, etc. It is not possible to control or block ajax requests in there. It's merely a *listener* function.

But you want to invoke your confirm dialog *before* the ajax request is ever sent. You need to hook on the `onclick` attrubute of the button instead and let the function return `true` or `false` depending on the outcome. In simplest form, with the builtin JavaScript `confirm()` function, it should look like this:

```html
<h:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" />
</h:commandButton>
```

When using the jQuery confirm dialog function which in turn invokes a hidden button as you have now, you should be using a normal button to open the jQuery confirm dialog, not a command button sending an ajax request.

```html
<h:button value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog('Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />
```

**Update**: as to altering the button's value and disabling it, just pass the button itself into the JS function where you alter it the usual way:

```html
<h:button value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog(this, 'Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />
```

with

```js
function deletedialog(button, message) {
    button.value = "Processing...";
    button.disabled = true;

    // ...
}
```

Don't forget to put them back to normal values when enduser chooses Cancel in the confirm dialog.

Comment: I'm confused. You propose to remove this code `<h:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" />
</h:commandButton>` and replace it with this code: `<h:button value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog('Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />` And keep the hidden button? I will test it. Would you show me how I can disable the button during execution time and how I can change the label?

Comment: The first part of my answer explains what the `onevent` is actually to be used for. The conclusion is that you should not use it for your particular purpose. You can disable the button and change the label in your JS function. Just pass the button as `this` to the function.

Comment: I edited the code - it works! Not about the disabled button and the changed label. Netbeans shows me that `h:button` does not have the attribute `onchange` but `h:commandButton` has it. Maybe you mean that I need to add `onevent` to the hidden button?

Comment: As said, just do it in your JS function. This is rather trivial now your biggest problem has been solved. I have anyway edited my answer with a kickoff example.

Comment: ok, when I add the `ajaxStatus` and the switch case into the JS code I suppose that I need also to add attributes to the JSF button?

Comment: You **do not** need the ajax event listener. Your button does not send an ajax request at all. Only the hidden button does.

Comment: As per your update, you should of course not re-enable the button when the enduser clicks OK in the dialog. Just keep it disabled. The `render="@form"` of the hidden button will automagically re-enable it because the form is updated.

Comment: There is one problem in the future that can appear: If the database operation takes more time to finish and render the page what will happen if the user clicks on other JSF page? I tested this case. The database operation will continue in background but the user when returns back the button will be again visible. Is it possible the java method to return `true` when the operation is finished?

Comment: Yes, I understand your point but what will happen if the SQL database operation took 2 minutes. During that time the user clicks on other JSF page and returns back. The button will be active but the database will not be finished.

Comment: Let the DB operation set some session or application wide toggle on start and reset it on finish. Then just let the page check the toggle. This is a whole subject apart.

Comment: Is there alternative way? For example the Java method called by the button returns "true" and the button is visible again.

Comment: There is no alternative way. What if the user's browser/PC crashes and the enduser has to restart the browser/PC and re-visit the page?